# Zeitform für weiterhin gültige Aussagen in ansonsten vergangenen Aussagen

Tags: time

Situation: In einer in der *Vergangenheit* geschriebenen (fiktiven oder realen) Geschichte oder Abhandlung kommt eine Aussage vor, die in der Realität weiterhin nachprüfbar korrekt und *nicht vergänglich* ist.

Beispiel: "Der Protagonist wanderte im Jahre 1801 von München nach Berlin. Der Weg **war/ist** knapp 600km lang. Unterwegs begegnete er einem Bekannten."

Frage: Sätze eins und drei sind eindeutig sowohl vergänglich als auch tatsächlich vergangen und daher korrekt in der Vergangenheitsform. Was kann, darf, sollte oder muss man beim zweiten Satz verwenden? Präsens oder Vergangenheit? Denn zweifelsfrei stimmt diese Aussage auch weiterhin in der realen Gegenwart, auch wenn die Geschichte in der Vergangenheit spielt. Die Vergangenheitsform könnte suggerieren, dass sich die Weglänge inzwischen verändert hätte, was ja nachweisbar nicht so ist.

Comment: OK, zugegeben: Ich hätte mir vielleicht ein noch konkreteres Beispiel ausdenken sollen, direkter Abstand Erde-Mond oder sowas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welche Zeitform hier zu verwenden ist, dürfte auf die Sichtweise ankommen, aus der das Geschehen erzählt wird. Folgendes ist vermutlich keine abschließende Aufzählung, aber mein Eindruck ist:

- Falls es sich beispielsweise um ein Sachbuch handelt, in dem über vergangene Ereignisse berichtet wird, sollte der zweite Satz "Der Weg ist knapp 600km lang." heißen. In solchen Texten werden aus heutiger Sicht Fakten vermittelt, und weiterhin gültige Fakten stehen somit auch im Präsens.
- Handelt es sich dagegen um eine Erzählung, die zumindest an dieser Textstelle Lesende in die Sicht des Hauptcharakters (oder auch einer anderen Person zum Zeitpunkt der Handlung) versetzt, wäre "Der Weg war knapp 600km lang." Ob diese Entfernungsangabe auch heute noch zutrifft, ist unerheblich (und dem Charakter, dessen Sicht man einnimmt, auch gar nicht bekannt); statt dessen stellt der Satz einfach einen weiteren Teil der Umgebungsbeschreibung in der komplett in Vergangenheitsform geschriebenen Handlung dar.

Answer (score 1):

Nutzt du Präsens, wird sich mancher Leser fragen: »Warum wählt er nicht Präteritum?« Nutzt du dagegen Präteritum, wird mancher fragen: »Warum nicht Präsens?«

Um solche Irritationen von vornherein zu vermeiden, ist es nicht immer das Schlechteste, auszuweichen und den Text so umzuformulieren, dass sich die Frage »Präsens oder Präteritum« erst gar nicht stellt.

> Der Hauptcharakter wanderte im Jahre 1801 von München nach Berlin,
> eine Strecke von knapp 600 Kilometern.

Das Stolpern des Lesers ist damit vermieden.

Wandernde Charaktere sind übrigens selten. »Hauptfigur« wäre ein Fortschritt; das Fachwort heißt »Protagonist«.

Answer (score 1):

Prinzipiell gilt, dass für Aussagen, die unabhängig von der Zeit wahr sind, die Gegenwart zu verwenden ist:

> Kugeln sind rund. 5 ist eine Primzahl.

Das würde eigentlich auf die Länge des Weges auch zutreffen.

Allerdings spielt deine Geschichte zu einem ganz bestimmten Zeitpunkt, der zufällig in der Vergangenheit liegt. Und da ist es nicht wesentlich hervorzuheben, dass der Weg immer die gleiche Länge hat. Wichtig ist, wie lang der Weg damals war, und damals war er eben knapp 600 km lang (übrigens mit Leerzeichen zwischen Zahl und Einheit).

Daher sind beide Varianten grammatikalisch richtig. Stilistisch ist es aber besser die grammatische Erzählzeit nicht zu wechseln, nur weil eine bestimmte Gegebenheit auch vor oder nach der konkreten Gegebenheit zutrifft.

Comment: Zu "übrigens mit Leerzeichen zwischen Zahl und Einheit": jein. :) Formal korrekt kommt zwischen Wert und Einheit ein geschütztes halbes Leerzeichen. Daher sind sowohl kein Leerzeichen als auch ein ungeschütztes ganzes Leerzeichen "halbfalsch". Ich entscheide mich immer für kein Leerzeichen, weil das dann wenigstens implizit geschützt ist (da nicht vorhanden). ("geschützt" steht hier für "kein automatischer Zeilenumbruch zwischen Zahl und Einheit")